# Nmap script prob

Tags: ipv6, nmap

I'm attempting to test the security of my site, with this brute force script:

https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-joomla-brute.html

But once started, I got an error:

```
# proxychains nmap -p 80 --script http-joomla-brute --script-args 'passdb=/dir/of/pass/list.txt,http-joomla-brute.threads=5,brute.firstonly=true' urlsite
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-20 00:24 CET
|DNS-request| urlsite
|S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| urlsite is ipsite
ipsite/0 looks like an IPv6 target specification -- you have to use the -6 option.
WARNING: No targets were specified, so 0 hosts scanned.
Nmap done: 0 IP addresses (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.29 seconds
```

Why `proxychains`? Because I'm using tor.

Can someone help me to understand what the error mean and how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

> ipsite/0 looks like an IPv6 target specification -- you have to use
>   the -6 option.

So just try adding `-6` to that command?

Answer (score 0):

Proxychains doesn't work with Nmap. Users have reported success using [Proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) instead.